# How do i implement Firebase Crashlytics in a Kotlin multiplataform mobile?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

If somebody did that before, can you tell me where did you put google-service.json? The android dependencies, did you put on them? In android module or in common module?
On IOS nor do I know how to get started.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing changes, your google services files would go in your android module / ios module as usual (i.e. in the same way you'd store them if not using KMM) and all dependencies would be set up as usual also.

If you want to call anything on `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()` from common code then you'd have two options:

- expect/actual mechanism and import crashlytics into the andorid source set of common code
- interface/impl with an interface in common code and an implementation in your android module & ios module